# Form is auto submitting but the data is not getting passed/received

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms

I have a problem in automating a form with hidden inputs in PHP. Basically I'm doing an input for a barcode scanner where the user will input the barcode and it will auto-submit, just like in a cash registry.

The conflict which I think is the cause of the problem is because of a conditional form. Here is a snippet:

```
<form method="post" id="form1">
  <div class="products">
    <input type="text" name="code" class="form-control" autofocus required onchange="submit()" />
  </div>
</form>
<?php 
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM product WHERE PRODUCT_CODE='.$code.' GROUP BY PRODUCT_CODE ORDER by PRODUCT_CODE ASC';
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
  if ($result):
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0):
      while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
?>
<form id="form2" method="post" action="pos.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $product['PRODUCT_CODE']; ?>" >
  <input type="hidden" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $product['NAME']; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $product['PRICE']; ?>" />
  <input type="submit" name="addpos" style="margin-top:5px;width: 462px" class="btn btn-info" value="Add"/>
</form>
<?php 
     endwhile;
    endif;
  endif;
?>
<script>
function submit() {
  document.getElementById("form1").submit();
}
  document.getElementById("form2").submit();       
</script>
```

The data from form1 has no trouble auto-submitting, then the form2 will auto-submit but nothing happens. I need help on how can I make form2 auto-submit correctly too. I have tried different event handling for form2 but nothing happens. I only know a little bit of javascript so that's just how my script turned out.

Thank you, Programming kings!

Comment: Can your select query return more than one record? Then you would be duplicating IDs for the forms you are creating there. (And if not - then why a _loop_ to begin with?)

Comment: And what is the whole point of this to begin with? Why do you need to submit a second form to `pos.php` - instead of doing what happens in there, directly when your _first_ form gets submitted?

Answer (score 0):

Because the second form is inside the while loop, if there are multiple results there will be multiple forms with the same id = "form2".
You need an increment variable $incrm = 2 inside the loop,
`form id='form<?php echo $incrm;?>'`,
with $incrm++ before ending it. I also recommend to add ann onchange event to the last input 'price' ; onchange = submit(this).

```
  function submit(inp) {
    inp.parentElement.submit();
  }
```